# Updating MXD data paths on new computer: a few questions

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, mxd, update

Fairly new to python, trying to update the data paths for several dozen MXD files to a new computer that doesn't have the "B" drive of the author.

Does the physical\logical data drive have to actually exist on the new computer, for python to reassign using "mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths" (say if the MXD references a B: drive, do I need to worry that my data is on the F: or C: drive?

I have a fairly simple script, that I keep getting syntax errors on:

```
import arcpy
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

mapdoc.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths("<the directory you are changing from>" , "<the directory you are changing to>")

mapdoc.save()

del mapdoc
```

Using: ArcGIS 10.3.1

Pseudo paths look like:

```
 from directory: "B:\Data_Directory\My Maps & Data\GIS_GDB_Layers\"

 to directory "C:\GIS_GDB_Layers\"
```

error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

I don't have a B:\ drive on my computer- apparently the person who forwarded the data & MXDs did.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Can you provide pseudo paths for the mapdoc.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths() method, and also the specific error message?  Syntax error usually means something syntax wise is incorrect which prevents the script from running.

Comment: Pseudo paths look like:

Answer (score 1):

It should make no difference whether the from paths exist on your machine.

Try checking what the layer data sources are set to by using this code snippet:

```
import arcpy
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
    print lyr.dataSource
del mapdoc
```